# Definition of TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body2?

Tags: android, material-design, android-appcompat, material-components-android, material-components

I am currently digging through the code of the Google IO 2019 android app.
In the [styles.xml](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/mobile/src/main/res/values/styles.xml) line 77 it says:

```
<style name="TextAppearance.IOSched.Body2" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body2" />
```

But where can I find the definition of the parent `TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body2`? I already have the IO project locally in my Android Studio, in case that helps to resolve what is behind that definition.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is defined in the [Material Components library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android).

Currently it is:

```
  <style name="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body2" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1">
    <item name="fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:letterSpacing">0.0178571429</item>
  </style>
```

You can find [here the latest](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/typography/res/values/styles.xml) implementation.

Comment: Great, thanks! Any idea where exactly to find the definition of the referenced parent TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1? :-)

Comment: The parent style is defined in androidx-appcompat library. You can find here the [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/appcompat/res/values/styles.xml?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F). The best way to navigate is to add the material components library in your project and then go through the styles.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. For the archive: https://material.io/design/typography/the-type-system.html is also useful here, as this is of course identical to what is defined in e.g. TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body2. It's more comfortable to read though :-)